# Extracting Numeric values from a text file by using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file including some numerical values, brackets, and commas as below:

```
[123,5],[345,21],[1567,34],[7689,234],....
```

All data are in one line.
I need to extract these numbers from this text file and need to define two variables like `X` and `Y` such that all the first elements in brackets are saved in variable X and all the second elements are saved in variable Y. I also would like to have these two variables `X` and `Y` in an excel file.

Comment: Then I guess you need to learn how to program in Python.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have started learning how to program in Python, and I have already done some programming in Python, but I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a file named `file.txt`, you can do the following:

```
import ast

with open('file.txt') as f:
    values = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    X, Y = zip(*values)
```